# Dropdown menu styling using bootstrap and nth child

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently building a site using the bootstrap 3 framework and I've come into a problem.  I'm trying to style the background of a drop down with list items. If I use the following code:

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a{
    background:#92a240;
    color:#fff;
}
```

it styles one shade of green, I then want to use the `:nth-child` selector to style the other links a darker green, I'm using this code:

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a:nth-child(odd){
    background:#b5c950;
    color:#fff;
}
```

however this makes all of the link backgrounds a light color and not the odd ones.

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your html structures is like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

and not like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#"></a>
        <a href="#"></a>
        <a href="#"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Since your css is going for the second html structure and I doubt it's like that one. If your structure is like the first one, then...:

Instead of targeting the `a` you should target the `li` with the `odd`:

```
.dropdown-menu > li:nth-child(odd) > a {}
```